# custom query in laravel datatable

Tags: laravel, laravel-datatables

i am trying to do a query on a table likes so

***tbl_bottle***

```
name | type | location
bot1    A       USA
bot2    B       
bot3    C       USA
bot4    A        UK
bot5    A        UK
```

so when i load front end it will show
this

```
name | type | location
bot1    A       USA
bot1    B       
bot3    C       USA
bot4    A        UK
bot5    A        UK
```

but when i type `bot1` in search it should give me :

```
name | type | location
bot1    A       USA
bot1    B
```

but what i get instead is

```
name | type | location
bot1    A       USA
bot1    B       
bot3    C       USA
```

this is what i have in my controller

```
     $bottle= tbl_bottle::select(
                'name',
                'type',
                'location'            
            )->where('location','=','USA')->OrWhere('location','=',' ');

return DataTables::of($bottle)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($bottle) {
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary got=to" id="' . $members->name. '">View Details</a>';
            })->make(true);
```

so the datatable displays this correctly but when i try to search it does not work correctly
what i mean is when i search

so in my front end all i have is

```
<table id="tbl_bottles" class="table">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Action</th>
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tbl_bottles').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('ajax.getBottles') }}",
        "columns": [
            { "data": 'name'},
            {"data": "type"},
            {"data": "location"},
            {"data":"action",orderable:false,searchable:false}
        ],
    });
});
</script>
```

the search input gets plugged in by the datatables 
the documentation iam using is https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: What do you mean by "so the datatable displays this correctly but when i try to search it does not work correctly"?

Comment: Edit your Question and post this query with the `Method` it belongs to in your `Controller`.

Comment: @Kaz okay will edit please give me a second

Comment: Are you passing the search `key word` to your controller?

Comment: `$bottle= tbl_bottle::select(
                'name',
                'type',
                'location'            
            )->where('location','=','USA')->OrWhere('location','=',' ');` in this query their is no where condition on name column.

Comment: @Kaz i have edited my question again please see if its clear enough

Comment: @6563cc10d2, where is the search input element where you type your search key words?

Comment: @Kaz when you use datatables it will automatically be generated

Comment: @Kaz have you done a Datatable with Laravel https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: Search Keyword Value of datatable can be retrieved on Controller using this param ``search[value]``. So `$search_keyword = $request->input('search')['value'];` Then use `->where('name','=', $search_keyword );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this worked for me

```
$bottle= tbl_bottle::select(
  'name',
  'type',
  'location'            
)->where(function($query) {
  $query->where('location','=','USA')->OrWhere('location','=',' ')
});

return DataTables::of($bottle)->make(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search by **bottle name**, then first you have to send the search `key word` (bottle name) along with request, so that you can get it in the Method.

Send the search `key word` in your `view`:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="key_word" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your `controller`, get the `key word`

Get the key word and assign it to a variable, and then when you query the bottles add the variable in the `where clause` like I showed below:

```
public function getBottles(Request $request){
  $keyWord = $request->key_word; // get the key word and assign it to a variable 
  $bottle= tbl_bottle::select(
                'name',
                'type',
                'location'            
            )->where('name','=', $keyWord)->

return DataTables::of($bottle)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($bottle) {
                return '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary got=to" id="' . $members->name. '">View Details</a>';
            })->make(true);
}
```

> Before you straight away take a `user input` into process, you have to validate it, but those things are besides this question boundary. My answer is only for what you have asked for.

Comment: @6563cc10d2, as you said that the search key words attributes will automatically be injected into your jQuery method, do a `dd($request->all());`, in the controller's method and let me know the output of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (for raw query)

```
$searchValue = $request->input('search')['value']; // Search value from datatable
//-- END DEFAULT DATATABLE QUERY PARAMETER

//-- START DYNAMIC QUERY BINDING
$conditions = '1 = 1';
if (!empty($searchValue)) {
    $conditions .= " AND name LIKE '%" . trim($searchValue) . "%'";
}
//-- END DYNAMIC QUERY BINDING

//-- WE MUST HAVE COUNT ALL RECORDS WITHOUT ANY FILTERS
$countAll = \App\tbl_bottle::count();

//-- CREATE DEFAULT LARAVEL PAGING
$paginate = \App\tbl_bottle::select('*')
    ->whereRaw($conditions)
    ->paginate($limit, ["*"], 'page', $page);
```

Or you can see my blog post [Laravel datatables](https://odenktools.com/jquery-datatables-laravel6-pagination/) for more details. Its provide sorting and searching too.

Comment: can you add relevant section from the link here? in that case the information stays here despite the link staying up or going